# Rails 4 - Mailer can't find template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

Im trying to learn how to use rails mailers.

I have made a mailer folder, with a folder inside it called user_mailer.rb. It has:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    layout 'transactional_mailer'

  def user_invite

    mail(
      :subject => "You've been invited to join a research project team",
      :to  => 'test@tester.com',
      :from => 'test@tester.com'
      )
  end
end
```

In my layout for transactional_mailer.html.erb, I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%= yield %>

<style>

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
    }

</style>
```

Then, In my views/Users/user_invite.html.erb

Hi ,

When I save all of this and try it in my console, by writing:

```
UserMailer.user_invite.deliver_now
```

I get an error that says:

```
UserMailer#user_invite: processed outbound mail in 65.4ms
ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template user_mailer/user_invite with "mailer". Searched in:
  * "user_mailer"
```

I don't know what this error message means or how I solve this problem. Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

I have also tried making a folder under my views directory called 'user_mailer'. In that folder, I tried adding a file called user_invite.html.erb - but it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem is here:**

You have to put your view `user_invite.html.erb` in `views/user_mailer/user_invite.html.erb` not in `views/users/user_invite.html.erb`

if you created your mailer manually remove it and  from console try

```
$ rails g mailer user user_invite
```

Then there automatically a new def called user_invite and view in user_mailer folder.

**I hope it works now**

Comment: no that was my second attempt (described above). It doesnt work either. I get the same error message as before

Comment: Also - I can't try your suggestion to use a generator because I get this error: The name 'User' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.

Comment: What is the result when you tried @Pradeep Sapkota's first solution? i.e.:  `put the user_invite.html.erb in views/user_mailter/user_invite.html.erb?`

Answer (score 0):

try to define the layout from your application mailer.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'Example <noreply@example.com>'
  layout 'transactional_mailer' #app/views/layouts/transactional_mailer.html.erb
end
```